# Need Sample code to user BULK API with XML format

Tags: bulk-api

Can someone share or point me to BULK API JAVA sample code for XML format .  I can see the JAVA example for csv format in below link.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_code_walkthrough.htm

If I want to change request from CSV format with XML format.What and Where I need to change. Even an quick guidance or explanation would work..thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

I would have have some tool like "XML2CSV Spreadsheet Converter 1.0" to convert the XML to CSV and used the sample java code of BULK API instead.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Bartley: Here is the link for [XML2CSV Spreadsheet Converter](http://www.sourcecodeonline.com/details/xml2csv_spreadsheet_converter.html)